# Find all objects in children that contain a script who implements an interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

Suppose I have a GameObject `A` that has a lot of children `a1`, `a2`, ..., `an`.

How can I find a list of an interface implemented by some of the children of `A`?

---

I tried adapting [glitcher's answer from here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/863509/how-can-i-find-all-objects-that-have-a-script-that.html) but when I executed, I got a stack overflow.

```
public static List<T> FindObjectsWithInterfaceInChildren<T>(this GameObject root)
{
    List<T> interfaces = new List<T>();
    T[] childrenInterfaces = root.GetComponentsInChildren<T>();
    foreach (var childInterface in childrenInterfaces) interfaces.Add(childInterface);
    return interfaces;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this extension method? As is I do not see why this causes a stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This extension method doesn't make any sense.

It basically simply returns

```
return root.GetComponentsInChildren<T>().ToList();
```

or

```
return new List<T>(root.GetComponentsInChildren<T>());
```

So you can as well directly use one of these instead if you really need it as a list at all.

Afaik `GetComponentsInChildren` was actually changed a while ago **and should now work just fine for interfaces**. => This already is the answer to your question.

Additionally I would pass in "true" to also find inactive and disabled children

---

In general note that `GetComponentsInChildren` includes components that are attached to the `root` object itself.

---

The link you referenced was rather for finding **ALL** objects of a certain interface in the **entire scene(s)** and goes like e.g.

```
public static T[] FindObjectssOfTypeAll<T>(bool includeInactiveAndDisabled)
{
    var output = new List<T>();
    // Go through all scenes
    for(var i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCount; i++)
    {
        var scene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i);

        // Go through all root objects
        foreach(var root in scene.GetRootGameObjects)
        {
            // get all children
            output.AddRange(root.GetComponentsInChildren(includeInactiveAndDisabled));
        }
    }
    // Consider rather returning "List<T>" and skip the "ToArray"
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: But I need to find all objects with a certain interface AND are children of a given root object.

Comment: @Daniel as said `root.GetComponentsInChildren<IYourInterface>()` already does exactly this ...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought this method wouldn't catch interfaces.